# Do Rails controllers URL unencode params for me?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rack

If a url parameter comes in urlencoded, does rails decode it for me, or do I have to call CGI::unencode myself?

(I'm asking because I'm seeing what is I think inconsistent behavior, and may be a bug in either rails or rspec, but wanted to ask here first to get a sanity check)

Comment: relevant rspec ticket: http://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/issues/issue/201

Comment: Looks like it's a real bug/problem with rails, see this ticket: https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/5869-params-in-functional-tests-not-sent-to-controller-encoded

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, Rails will automatically decode GET and POST values for you.

Comment: ... but not path params. (?)